# Angular Formly - Disable individual Radio Options

Tags: angular, angular-formly

I'm trying to disable one Radio Button (e.g  the first one) Option trough angular formly Fields.

```
          options: [
            {
              value: 1,
              label: 1,
            },
            {
              value: 2,
              label: 2
            },
            {
              value: 3,
              label: 3
            }
          ]
```

This doesn't work

```
                {
                  value: 1,
                  label: 1,
                  disable: 'true' //also tried true or 'disabled'
                },
```

I have also tried the following, unfortunately without success

```
        hooks: {
          onInit: (field) => {
            field.expressionProperties.options[0].disabled = true;
          }
```

Anyone have some ideas how can I achieve this? In HTML it would be easy to set the disabled="disabled" attribute..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my outdated @ngx-formly/core Version

I updated from 5.5.1 to 5.10.1 and it works now

Answer (score 1):

Generally there are two ways for that:

1. **Using `[attr.disabled]`**
2. **Using `fieldset` tag**

> 1. Using `[attr.disabled]`

```html
<input type="radio" name="enabled" [attr.disabled]="null" />Enabled radio
<input type="radio" name="disabled" [attr.disabled]="false" />Disabled radio
```

> 2. Using `fieldset` tag

```html
<fieldset [disabled]=true>
    <input type="radio" name="fieldsetTest" />Disable
</fieldset>
```

If you want control the `disable\enable` dynamically in your `Component.ts` you can try something like this:

> Component.ts

```js
options = [
          {
           value: 1,
           label: 1,
           disable: null //for 'disabled' mode
           },
           {
           value: 2,
           label: 2,
           disable: 'false' //for 'enable' mode
           },
];
```

> Component.html

```html
<div *ngFor="let option of options">
  <input type="radio" name="enabled" [attr.disabled]="option.disable" />
</div>
```